# C preprocessing

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor

Why are certain strings replaced and others not replaced with #define?

```
$ cat test.c
#define X_ REPLACED
int main() {
  X_x();
  X_();
  return 0;
} 

$ gcc -E test.c
# 1 "test.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "test.c"

int main() {
  X_x();
  REPLACED();
  return 0;
}
```

Above `X_();` is replaced but `X_x();` is not. What are the rules? I can't find any info on this anywhere despite a long investigation.

Reason I'm looking at this is: I want to link to an FFT library (FFTW) whose routine names start with fftwf_, fftw_, fftwl_ or fftwq_ depending on whether single, double, long double or quadratic precision is in use.

(gcc version: 4.4.3)

Comment: I can start to see your reason for wanting this, but you should elaborate further. Are you trying to write your code to work regardless of which of those is used, so that a few `#define`s or `-D` flags can change which set your code uses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the preprocessor works on a token-by-token basis, and `X_x` counts as one token, hence it is ignored by the `#define`. If you need `X_x` to become `REPLACEDx()`, use sed or any other regexer to preprocess the code.

Because macros are dumb, argument introspection is impossible, so you can't really do `#define fft_func(mytype
If you want to do that effect without regexes, use

```
#define CONCAT2(x, y) x##y
#define CONCAT(x, y) CONCAT2(x, y)
#define FFTW_FUNC(fft_type, fft_func) CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(fftw, fft_type), _), fft_func)

int main() {
// ...
FFTW_FUNC(type, func)(args);
// ...
}
```

For fft types:

```
#define FFTWT_FLOAT f
#define FFTWT_DOUBLE
#define FFTWT_LONG_DOUBLE l
#define FFTWT_QUAD_PRECISION q
```

Comment: For an example of how bad this would be: #define max(a,b) ... (now go look for where you have "max" *anywhere*).

Comment: Surely you mean `#define CONCAT(x, y) CONCAT2(x, y)`

Comment: @ChrisLutz fixed; i knew i forgot to add something

Comment: @crashmstr A sledgehammer has its uses. Polishing fine china is not one of them. It is up to the coder to be judicious.

Comment: I'd use `#ifndef FFTW_TYPE` / `#define FFTWT FFTWT_DOUBLE` / `#endif` / `#define FFTW(funcname) FFTW_FUNC(FFTWT, funcname)` so that a user could pass `-DFFTWT=FFTWT_LONG_DOUBLE` on the command-line and change what the compiled file uses. A little additional machinery could set up an appropriate `typedef`, and if a bit of code absolutely required a specific type at any point it'd still be avaliable.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you that is exactly what I wanted. I've edited a bit your solution as follow:

```
#ifdef single
  #define myType fftwf_
#else
  #ifdef double
    #define myType fftw_
  #endif
#endif

#define CONCAT(x, y) x##y
#define FFTW_FUNC(fft_type, fft_func) CONCAT(fft_type, fft_func)

int main() {
  //
  FFTW_FUNC(myType, func)(args);
  //                                                   
}
```

The above gives:

```
$ gcc -E -Ddouble test.c; gcc -E -Dsingle test.c
# 1 "test.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"    
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "test.c"
# 12 "test.c"
int main() {

  fftw_func(args);

}
# 1 "test.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "test.c"
# 12 "test.c"
int main() {

  fftwf_func(args);

}
```